# Understanding inheritance and passing child variable to the parent class

Tags: python, args, keyword-argument

i read a lot but still can't figure out how to pass a child variable to the parent class:

```
class anyIF_traffic(object):
    def __init__(self, logpath, typeOfTraffic='cha', name='mytest', port='6060'):
        try:
            assert port in [None, '6060', '6161', '6389', '6636']
            print "PORT: %s"%(port)
            self.port = port
        except AssertionError, msg:
            print "Exception"
            sys.exit (1)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.port

class a_traffic(anyIF_traffic):
    def _init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.port = '6161'
        anyIF_traffic.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

class b_traffic(anyIF_traffic):
    def _init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.port = '6389'
        anyIF_traffic.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

port = a_traffic(logpath='c://')
print "A. %s"%(port)

port = a_traffic(logpath='c://')
print "B. %s"%(port)

OUT: 
A. 6060

OUT: 
B. 6060
```

What i would like to get is:

```
OUT: 
A. 6161

OUT: 
B. 6389
```

But when i run it i will always get the default value of '6060' since this is declared in the parent class _*init*.

Of course i could do:

```
port = a_traffic(logpath='c://', port='6161')
print "A. %s"%(port)

OUT: 
A. 6161
```

But i am trying to have as much as possible less parameters for the user to take care off.

I know my problem is that i haven't fully understand pythons inheritance of classes and still new in python.

Thanks in adv.

Comment: Where did you take those terrible class names from? :) Also, note that `port` should be an `int` not a `str`; where you need it as a string, just do `str(port)`.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments and answers, but i did try those suggestions, but i still get the same output! Do i have maybe to change also my parent class?

Comment: I got it, stupid newbie error! It works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in strictly adhering to the inheritance paradigm, simply pass port 6161 into the super class constructor:

```
class a_traffic(anyIF_traffic):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if len(args) == 5:
            args[4] = '6161'
        else:
            kwargs['port'] = '6161'
        super(a_traffic, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you initialized the parent, including the default port 6060, after assigning the override in the child class. Just initialize the parent first:

```
class a_traffic(anyIF_traffic):
    def _init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        anyIF_traffic.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.port = '6161'
```

Sometimes its useful to do some pre-setup before calling the parent **init**, but the other 99% of the time, initialize the parent first.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `port` to have a different default in the child class, you can simply manipulate the keyword argument dictionary before you pass it along to the parent class:

```
class a_traffic(anyIF_traffic):
    def _init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if len(args) < 4 and "port" not in kwargs:
            kwargs["port"] = "6161"
        anyIF_traffic.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

This allows there to be only one place where `self.port` gets assigned, so you don't need to worry about whether the child class is overwriting the value set by the parent class, or vise versa.